# while updating property 'start' in shadow node of type in react native

Tags: react-native

I run the app  and then I login into the system and it will close immediately so what will I do

[image]

render() {
if (Platform.OS === "android") {
return (

{this.renderContentForForm()}

);
} else {
return (


{this.renderContentForForm()}


);
}
}

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: I share the code